# How to invoke rest api using Grafana?

Tags: grafana

Hi I Have angular project that's call a rest API and using get request I am able to see my JSON data in postman.
I want to visualize it using GRAFANA. Can anybody help?

Comment: Hi, you need to be more specific; give some example. It is hard to understand what you want

Comment: I have to modified JSON data in such a way that grafna can understand.